# How can I rebuild a razed city?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Several cities have been razed around the map by enemy forces, I've tried moving my forces onto the "dead" city to interact and sending different agents and checking through the build screen but there's nothing.

How can I rebuild a city after it's been razed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you can settle there. Humans and Vampires can only settle in areas originally settled by Humans or Vampires. Likewise with Orcs and Dwarves. Chaos can't settle anywhere. Then move an army there. You should get a popup that asks you to spend an amount of currency and soldiers to revitalize the settlement.
[image]
 After that you need to build the first level of the town's main building.
[image]

Comment: I've tried that with one of my own cities (damn chaos) but no popup, is there a cooldown (fires stop burning down?) or something?

Comment: @Rob You have to make sure your army is big enough. Last time I tried I needed atleast 8 units. The more units the cheaper it becomes to revitalize the settlement, but you'll also lose some troops to it.

Comment: @Rob When you hover the cursor over the ruins it should show up as a sword, like an "attack" (so it will not be possible if you are marching, for example). I have been able to rebuild cities with just a single lord, it just gets cheaper the more troops you have.

Comment: And that worked, I think my army was too small before or something. Horah! Just in time for Chaos to turn up.